# SvelteKit: Cannot reference store value inside <script context="module" />

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, svelte-store

SvelteKit / Svelte : Not able to get or set (Read or Write) values from the "store" in the context module.

```
import {selectedStore} from "src/storelocation";

<script context="module">
  export const load = async ({params})=> {
    
     $selectedStore.value // throwing error
  }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
import {selectedStore} from "src/storelocation";
import { get } from 'svelte/store';

<script context="module">
export const load = async ({params})=> {

  // use this
 get(selectedStore).value;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Would you mind explaining why this is the case or pointing me somewhere to find out?

Comment: @BlaviButcher If I understand correctly, the reason is because [Variables defined in module scripts are not reactive](https://svelte.dev/docs#component-format-script-context-module), therefore you can't access stores using reactive notation (`$mystore`) but manually calling store methods is ok (`mystore.set(…)` and `get(mystore).value`). [Here's a github issue with an example](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/4306).